# nsis license page print button - why does the text appear in Chinese?

Tags: nsis

I've been searching for hours, but have not found a solution.  Ever switching to NSIS 3.x, the license page Print button text appears in Chinese.  I am using MUI2.  I cannot find how to make it display the text in English.  The rest of the form text and the other buttons are in English.  The Print button also appeared correctly in NSIS 2.x using the exact same .nsi file we are using.

Any ideas how to get this to work besides reverting NSIS versions?

Comment: It does not have a print button out of the box, where did you get the print button from?

Comment: Do you have `Unicode true` in your script?

Comment: I'm assuming it's a Print button.  It appears to the right of the text that says "If you accept the terms of the agreement, ....".  It's always been there.

Comment: Post your licensepage code or link to the wiki page where you got the print functionality from.

Comment: I tried putting in a `Unicode true` statement in, but the NSIS compiler gave me an error no matter where I put it.

Comment: Oh, hold on.  I now see that the .nsi file is calling `nsRichEdit::AddPrintButton` to add the button.  I had not noticed this before. I did not originally create this installer.  I will have to try to figure out what this is doing.

Comment: Ok, it appears that nsRichEdit must be defunct now.  Since I can't find any documentation on how to change the language settings it uses, I just removed the print button completely from the page.

Answer (score 1):

The plug-in works just fine for me, you must have copied to wrong .DLL because when a Unicode plug-in tries to display ANSI text it [tends to look Chinese](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140930-00/?p=43953).

When using NSIS v2 you can just extract NsRichEdit.zip to the root of the NSIS installation folder.

If you are using NSIS v3 you must put NsRichEdit.zip:\Plugins\nsRichEdit.dll in \NSIS\Plugins\x86-ansi\ and NsRichEdit.zip:\Unicode\Plugins\nsRichEdit.dll in \NSIS\Plugins\x86-unicode.

You can then choose if you want to create a Unicode or ANSI installer:

```
Name `nsRichEdit Test`
OutFile nsRichEdit.exe
RequestExecutionLevel user
Unicode True ; This creates a Unicode installer

PageEx License
  PageCallbacks `` License_Show
  LicenseData Example.nsi
PageExEnd

Function License_Show
  nsRichEdit::AddPrintButton `&Print` `$(^Name) License Agreement`
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd
```

Comment: I had copied the dll to the x86-ansi directory previously because I was not using `Unicode True`.  Yesterday I tried copying the driver to the x86-unicode directory, but that did not correct the issue.  When I tried putting in `Unicode True` yesterday, I kept getting an error when trying to build my installer.  But I think I did not put it up high enough in the .nsi file.  Today when I put it near the top I was able to build the installer, and the Print button text is correct.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: The .zip file has two plug-in .dll files and if you copy the wrong one things will break in strange ways. Unicode True must come before any code in sections/functions but the compiler should give you a clue about this in the error message.

Comment: Anders, could you please advise, why my installer giving me a blank Print button, without text? Possible some different syntax here: `nsRichEdit::AddPrintButton `&Print` `$(^Name) License Agreement``